# Debian 9.4: cannot install php7.2-curl

Tags: debian, curl, php7

Trying to install php7.2-curl library from a well-known repository deb.sury.org on Debian 9.4. But it gives the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-curl : Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, how could I install libcurl4, it looks like there's just libcurl3 in a normal Debian repository?

Comment: The easiest way of having it is installing Debian testing

Comment: Sorry, I'm a kind of newbie in Linux world, it's a virtual server I've bought on one of cloud providers, so, should I completely reinstall Debian or there's an easier way to switch to testing version?

Comment: I have installed Debian Buster (which is current testing version) but it didn't help.

Comment: Buster has his own php7.2-curl, do not use the repository

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution here is upgrading to Debian 10/Buster, as it already has `php7.2-curl` and the respective dependencies by default.

Obviously, upgrading to Buster, the repository  deb.sury.org is not needed.

From Debian packages: https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.2-curl

Answer (score 1):

Installing libcurl4 worked for me using

```
apt install libcurl4
```

Then installed php7.2-curl, restarted apache2 without an issue.